# Calculate state space matrices from the Lagrangian

Tags: dynamic, linear-algebra, nonlinear

I have a Lagrangian with two inputs (`Tin1,Tin2`) and two variables (`x1[t], x2[t]`). I want to calculate the linear state space model for it using Matlab or Mathematica. The state variables should be `x1[t], x2[t], x1'[t], x2'[t]`. Is there a way for it?

```
L = 0.5*m1*(l1/2)^2*(x1'[t])^2 + 0.5*I1*(x1'[t])^2 - 0.5*m1*g*l1*Sin[x1[t]] + 
0.5*I2*(x1'[t])^2 +       0.5*m2*l1^2*(x1'[t])^2 + 0.5*m2*(l2/2)^2*(x1'[t] +
 x2'[t])^2 + 0.5*m2*l1*l2*x1'[t]*(x1'[t] + x2'[t]) Cos[x2[t]] + 
0.5*I2*(x2'[t])^2 - m2*g*l1*Sin[x1[t]] - 0.5*m2*g*l2*Sin[x1[t] + x2[t]] + I2*x1'[t]*x2'[t];
```

I know the below codes should be the first step of the whole calculation:

```
D[D[L, x1'[t]], t] - D[L, x1[t]] == Tin1
D[D[L, x2'[t]], t] - D[L, x2[t]] == Tin2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AffineStateSpaceModel.html#25903871).

For your example:

```
eqns = Table[D[D[L, Derivative[1][q][t]], t] - D[L, q[t]] == 
Subscript[T, q][t], {q, {x1, x2}}];

StateSpaceModel[eqns, {x1[t], x2[t]}, {Subscript[T, x1][t], 
 Subscript[T, x2][t]}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]
```

[image]

Comment: I could not find this example in the documentation unfortunately @Suba Thomas

Comment: The link I have in the answer http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AffineStateSpaceModel.html#25903871 shows how to get  an `AffineStateSpaceModel`. It is the same workflow for a `StateSpaceModel`. What else do you need.

Comment: well, I used the AffineStateSpaceModel but did not work! I have it like this:
sys1 = D[D[L, x1'[t]], t] - D[L, x1[t]] == Tin1
sys2 = D[D[L, x2'[t]], t] - D[L, x2[t]] == Tin2

AffineStateSpaceModel[Join[sys1, sys2], {x1[t], x2[t], x1'[t], 
   x2'[t]}, {Tin1, Tin2}, t] // Simplify
@Suba Thomas

Comment: Sure, your code is so full of errors and naturally it will not work. 1.Tin1 is not the same as Tin1[t]. 2. Is the result of your `Join` a list of equations? 3. What are the outputs of your `AffineStateSpaceModel`?

Comment: Tin1 is not defined to be time variant, so it should not be Tin1[t] (but even if it would be defined as Tin1[t] it does not work), and yes the result of the join is a list of equations. the output is x1[t] I suppose.

AffineStateSpaceModel[
 Join[sys1, sys2], {x1[t], x2[t], x1'[t], 
  x2'[t]}, {Tin1, Tin2}, {x1[t]}, t]
@Suba Thomas

Comment: Here's the solution! AffineStateSpaceModel[{sys1, sys2}, {x1[t], x2[t], x1'[t], x2'[t]}, {Tin1[t], Tin2[t]}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]. When constructing the model all states and input variables function of t. The equation is x'(t)==A.x(t)+B.u(t). u is specified as a function of t. A constant input is just a special case during simulation or analysis.

Comment: This is still nonlinear, why? @Suba Thomas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70114/discussion-between-suba-thomas-and-f-r).

Answer (score 2):

Your statespace variables are `x1[t],x2[t],x1'[t],x2'[t]`

With

```
sys={D[D[L, x1'[t]], t] - D[L, x1[t]] == Tin1,D[D[L, x2'[t]], t] - D[L, x2[t]]==  Tin2}
```

and the substitution

```
subst={x1'[t]->v1[t],x1''[t]->v1'[t],x2'[t]->v2[t],x2''[t]->v2'[t]}
sys4=Join[sys/.subst,{x1'[t]==v1[t],x2'[t]==v2[t]}]
```

you get 4 ode's, which can be solved

```
rS = {x1'[t], v1'[t], x2'[t], v2'[t]}  /.Solve[sys4, {x1'[t], v1'[t],x2'[t], v2'[t]} ][[1]]
(* 

{1. v1[t], -((-1. (I2 + 0.25 l2^2 m2 + 
     0.5 l1 l2 m2 Cos[x2[t]]) (-1. Tin2 + 
     0.5 g l2 m2 Cos[x1[t] + x2[t]] - 
     0.5 l1 l2 m2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t] v2[t] + 
     0.5 l1 l2 m2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t] (v1[t] + v2[t])) + (1. I2 + 
     0.25 l2^2 m2) (-1. Tin1 + 0.5 g l1 m1 Cos[x1[t]] + 
     g l1 m2 Cos[x1[t]] + 0.5 g l2 m2 Cos[x1[t] + x2[t]] - 
     0.5 l1 l2 m2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t] v2[t] - 
     0.5 l1 l2 m2 Sin[x2[t]] v2[t] (v1[t] + v2[t])))/(0. + 
  1. I1 I2 + 0.25 I2 l1^2 m1 + 1. I2 l1^2 m2 + 0.25 I1 l2^2 m2 + 
  0.0625 l1^2 l2^2 m1 m2 + 0.25 l1^2 l2^2 m2^2 - 
  0.25 l1^2 l2^2 m2^2 Cos[x2[t]]^2)), 
  1. v2[t], -((0.5 (2. I2^2 Tin1 + 1. I2 l2^2 m2 Tin1 + 
    0.125 l2^4 m2^2 Tin1 - 2. I1 I2 Tin2 - 2. I2^2 Tin2 - 
    0.5 I2 l1^2 m1 Tin2 - 2. I2 l1^2 m2 Tin2 - 
    0.5 I1 l2^2 m2 Tin2 - 1. I2 l2^2 m2 Tin2 - 
    0.125 l1^2 l2^2 m1 m2 Tin2 - 0.5 l1^2 l2^2 m2^2 Tin2 - 
    0.125 l2^4 m2^2 Tin2 - 1. g I2^2 l1 m1 Cos[x1[t]] - 
    2. g I2^2 l1 m2 Cos[x1[t]] - 
    0.5 g I2 l1 l2^2 m1 m2 Cos[x1[t]] - 
    1. g I2 l1 l2^2 m2^2 Cos[x1[t]] - 
    0.0625 g l1 l2^4 m1 m2^2 Cos[x1[t]] - 
    0.125 g l1 l2^4 m2^3 Cos[x1[t]] + 
    1. I2 l1 l2 m2 Tin1 Cos[x2[t]] + 
    0.25 l1 l2^3 m2^2 Tin1 Cos[x2[t]] - 
    2. I2 l1 l2 m2 Tin2 Cos[x2[t]] - 
    0.5 l1 l2^3 m2^2 Tin2 Cos[x2[t]] - 
    0.5 g I2 l1^2 l2 m1 m2 Cos[x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]] - 
    1. g I2 l1^2 l2 m2^2 Cos[x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]] - 
    0.125 g l1^2 l2^3 m1 m2^2 Cos[x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]] - 
    0.25 g l1^2 l2^3 m2^3 Cos[x1[t]] Cos[x2[t]] + 
    1. g I1 I2 l2 m2 Cos[x1[t] + x2[t]] + 
    0.25 g I2 l1^2 l2 m1 m2 Cos[x1[t] + x2[t]] + 
    1. g I2 l1^2 l2 m2^2 Cos[x1[t] + x2[t]] + 
    0.25 g I1 l2^3 m2^2 Cos[x1[t] + x2[t]] + 
    0.0625 g l1^2 l2^3 m1 m2^2 Cos[x1[t] + x2[t]] + 
    0.25 g l1^2 l2^3 m2^3 Cos[x1[t] + x2[t]] + 
    0.5 g I2 l1 l2^2 m2^2 Cos[x2[t]] Cos[x1[t] + x2[t]] + 
    0.125 g l1 l2^4 m2^3 Cos[x2[t]] Cos[x1[t] + x2[t]] + 
    1. I1 I2 l1 l2 m2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    1. I2^2 l1 l2 m2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    0.25 I2 l1^3 l2 m1 m2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    1. I2 l1^3 l2 m2^2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    0.25 I1 l1 l2^3 m2^2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    0.5 I2 l1 l2^3 m2^2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    0.0625 l1^3 l2^3 m1 m2^2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    0.25 l1^3 l2^3 m2^3 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    0.0625 l1 l2^5 m2^3 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    1. I2 l1^2 l2^2 m2^2 Cos[x2[t]] Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    0.25 l1^2 l2^4 m2^3 Cos[x2[t]] Sin[x2[t]] v1[t]^2 + 
    2. I2^2 l1 l2 m2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t] v2[t] + 
    1. I2 l1 l2^3 m2^2 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t] v2[t] + 
    0.125 l1 l2^5 m2^3 Sin[x2[t]] v1[t] v2[t] + 
    1. I2 l1^2 l2^2 m2^2 Cos[x2[t]] Sin[x2[t]] v1[t] v2[t] + 
    0.25 l1^2 l2^4 m2^3 Cos[x2[t]] Sin[x2[t]] v1[t] v2[t] + 
    1. I2^2 l1 l2 m2 Sin[x2[t]] v2[t]^2 + 
    0.5 I2 l1 l2^3 m2^2 Sin[x2[t]] v2[t]^2 + 
    0.0625 l1 l2^5 m2^3 Sin[x2[t]] v2[t]^2 + 
    0.5 I2 l1^2 l2^2 m2^2 Cos[x2[t]] Sin[x2[t]] v2[t]^2 + 
    0.125 l1^2 l2^4 m2^3 Cos[x2[t]] Sin[x2[t]] v2[
      t]^2))/((1. I2 + 0.25 l2^2 m2) (1. I1 I2 + 
    0.25 I2 l1^2 m1 + 1. I2 l1^2 m2 + 0.25 I1 l2^2 m2 + 
    0.0625 l1^2 l2^2 m1 m2 + 0.25 l1^2 l2^2 m2^2 - 
    0.25 l1^2 l2^2 m2^2 Cos[x2[t]]^2)))}
*)
```

The nonlinear statespace differentialequation is of the  form 
{x1'[t], v1'[t], x2'[t], v2'[t]}==rS . Linearization of rS gives the linear statespace model.

Comment: Hi, thanks, that gives just a differential equations diffinition for each state, and not the linearized state space model in a form of x'=Ax+Bu @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: Sorry, my answer is completed.

Comment: well, I could not get an answer form this code, there is an error in it, did you get the result from this? @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: @F R: The four lines of code  in my answer are ok, again tested in my notebook

Comment: Can you post the state space that you get here? @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: I'm after the linearized state space in a form of x'=Ax+Bu! with being able to get it in just one line code (since I will send the equations from Matlab to Mathematica to solve it and read it back). This si not the result that I'm looking for! @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: I gave you the right side of the statespace equation. Linearization is your job because only you know the equilibrium of your system..